# Azure SDK is missing on VS 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-sdk

After installing the new Visual Studio 2017 RC, I gave a problem with the Azure SDK.
The error is as follows:

> WAT080: Failed to locate the Microsoft Azure SDK. Please make sure the
>   Microsoft Azure SDK v2.9 is installed

When installing, I completely selected all the components provided by the installer. I already tried to reinstall and repair but nothing works.
Any ideas?

Comment: Post your issue here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html